# Apply a custom gate to qubits in separate quantum registers

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-gate

Let there be a custom gate (simply called `gate` that takes $N$ qubits as input. Also, let $A$ of those qubits be in `first_register` and $B$ of those qubits be in `second_register` ($B = N-A$, obviously).
Both registers are `QuantumRegisters`.

How to append this custom gate to circuit, like what to write in `circuit.append(gate, HERE)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply merge the lists of qubits from two quantum registers or more as any python lists using "+" sign. For example

```
gate = UnitaryGate(random_unitary(2 ** 4).data, 'RND-U16')

qr1 = QuantumRegister(2, 'q')
qr2 = QuantumRegister(3, 'a')
circ = QuantumCircuit(qr1, qr2)

circ.mct(qr1[0:2] + qr2[0:2], qr2[2])
circ.append(gate, qr1[1:2] + qr2[0:3])
```

The result:

[image]